# I am looking for a definition of xs used in the Here .xsds or a location for base type definitions

Tags: here-api

A where to find Here .xsd definitions request.

In use of Here .xsds I am missing the definition for "xs" and/or I need the location of the .xsd file that defines the geocoding base types (which are documented [here](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/enterprise-routing/topics/resource-types-base.html)).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for schema location for Routing API, the following link has the links to required schema locations :

https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/routing/topics/resources.html